# How to use character slots for searching in R? (See code)

Tags: r, class, dataframe, slot

I'm diving into classes in R and I found something interesting about using slots in order to make easier searching for observations in a given database. Using mtcars database I made the following:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$car_name<- rownames(mtcars) #This will be used for my character slot
mtcars
```

Then I define a class:

```
setClass("cars", 
    slots=c("name"="character",
    "hp"= "numeric",
    "mpg"= "numeric",
    "cyl"= "numeric")
)
```

And create a whole instance with new:

```
cars <- new("cars", name= mtcars$car_name, hp=mtcars$hp, mpg= mtcars$mpg, cyl= mtcars$cyl)
```

When variables are numeric, it simple to make simple searching such as:

```
sum(cars@hp<90 & cars@mpg<100)    #Number of cases
which(cars@hp<90 & cars@mpg<100)  #Position of cases
```

Now, I try to get the name for observations who met condition with:

```
cars@car_name & cars@hp< 90 & cars@mpg<100
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in cars@car_name & cars@hp < 90 :
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

What can I do, using my example as reference, to print the name or names of observations which met conditions? Is it compulsory to use SetMethods or something alike?

Any advice and suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: try this `cars@name[cars@hp< 90 & cars@mpg<100]` it will list the car's names with hp above 90 and mpg above 100. `car_name` is also not the name of your class. it is `name`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: What's the advantage of doing this? `sum(cars@hp<90 & cars@mpg<100) ` is exactly equivalent to `sum(mtcars$hp < 90 & mtcars$mpg < 100)`, you just replaced `$` with `@`.

Comment: It's not about advantages, it's just about learning how do classes work :)